# Can I create a colored vignette in Photoshop Elements 14?

Tags: photoshop-elements

After creating a black (or white) vignette using the guided edit in Photoshop Elements 14, can I then change it to a specific alternative colour?  If so, please tell me how. I am a beginner to the programme.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about graphics editing without a clear photographic context. Not all questions about graphics editors are on-topic just because they *can* be used for photo editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a layer, you can then apply the vignette to a mask. The mask could be used to apply color at varying degrees of transparency and with any color that you apply using a paint bucket.

Answer (score -2):

Yes using some frequency tricks , you can change the color. 
But as you are now beginner. That would be a new thing for you..

Check some tutorials on frequency separations and more. I saw a tutorial on the same long time ago.

Comment: Could you please try and summarise the contents of those tutorials in your answer? At the moment, this just says "go and read a tutorial" which doesn't really add any value to *this* site.